# Using ffmpeg with decimal wildcard

Tags: linux, macos, command-line, ffmpeg

I have a folder with PNG images of the following naming scheme:

```
IMG_0423.png
IMG_0424.png
...
IMG_0509.png
```

I would like to make an MP4 movie from these images, but I get an error message that `ffmpeg` cannot find these images:

```
$ ffmpeg -i IMG_%04d.png -vf "setpts=6*PTS" ../foo.mp4
ffmpeg version 0.7.13, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Dec 22 2012 12:45:08 with clang 4.1 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.11.65))
  configuration: --prefix=/opt/local --enable-swscale --enable-avfilter --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libtheora --enable-libdirac --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --disable-libopencore-amrnb --disable-libopencore-amrwb --mandir=/opt/local/share/man --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --cc=/usr/bin/clang --arch=x86_64 --enable-yasm --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid
  libavutil    50. 43. 0 / 50. 43. 0
  libavcodec   52.123. 0 / 52.123. 0
  libavformat  52.111. 0 / 52.111. 0
  libavdevice  52.  5. 0 / 52.  5. 0
  libavfilter   1. 80. 0 /  1. 80. 0
  libswscale    0. 14. 1 /  0. 14. 1
  libpostproc  51.  2. 0 / 51.  2. 0
./IMG_%04d.png: No such file or directory
```

Is there something I am missing about using this naming scheme with `ffmpeg`? Thanks for your advice.

**EDIT**

I am adding the output from running a modified command, which only results in the first frame:

```
Papillion:png alexpreynolds$ ../ffmpeg -start_number 423 -i "IMG_%04d.png" ../foo.mp4
ffmpeg version N-48159-g1501475-tessus Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Dec 21 2012 22:22:28 with llvm-gcc 4.2.1 (LLVM build 2336.1.00)
  configuration: --prefix=/Users/tessus/data/ext/ffmpeg/sw --as=yasm --extra-version=tessus --disable-shared --enable-static --disable-ffplay --disable-ffserver --enable-gpl --enable-pthreads --enable-postproc --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-libspeex --enable-bzlib --enable-zlib --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libxavs --enable-version3 --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libgsm --enable-libopus --enable-fontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libass --enable-filters --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil      52. 12.100 / 52. 12.100
  libavcodec     54. 81.100 / 54. 81.100
  libavformat    54. 49.102 / 54. 49.102
  libavdevice    54.  3.102 / 54.  3.102
  libavfilter     3. 29.100 /  3. 29.100
  libswscale      2.  1.103 /  2.  1.103
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
Input #0, image2, from 'IMG_%04d.png':
  Duration: 00:00:00.16, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgba, 640x480 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 4:3], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
File '../foo.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x10202da00] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 FastShuffle SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 0x10202da00] profile High, level 3.0
[libx264 @ 0x10202da00] 264 - core 128 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2012 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to '../foo.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf54.49.102
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=-1--1, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (png -> libx264)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=    4 fps=0.0 q=-2.0 Lsize=      54kB time=00:00:00.08 bitrate=5520.7kbits/s    
video:53kB audio:0kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 1.554395%
[libx264 @ 0x10202da00] frame I:1     Avg QP:26.72  size: 53541
[libx264 @ 0x10202da00] frame P:1     Avg QP:27.18  size:    27
[libx264 @ 0x10202da00] frame B:2     Avg QP:26.83  size:    40
[libx264 @ 0x10202da00] consecutive B-frames: 25.0%  0.0% 75.0%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x10202da00] mb I  I16..4:  3.3% 49.4% 47.2%
[libx264 @ 0x10202da00] mb P  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4:  0.2%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:99.8%
[libx264 @ 0x10202da00] mb B  I16..4:  0.1%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  1.0%  0.0%  0.0%  direct: 0.0%  skip:98.9%  L0: 5.2% L1:94.8% BI: 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x10202da00] 8x8 transform intra:49.3% inter:100.0%
[libx264 @ 0x10202da00] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 90.0% 91.1% 75.6% inter: 0.0% 0.0% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x10202da00] i16 v,h,dc,p: 14% 21% 12% 52%
[libx264 @ 0x10202da00] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 15% 20% 15%  6%  8%  7%  9%  7% 12%
[libx264 @ 0x10202da00] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 18% 22% 13%  7%  8%  9%  8%  6%  9%
[libx264 @ 0x10202da00] i8c dc,h,v,p: 53% 23% 15% 10%
[libx264 @ 0x10202da00] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x10202da00] kb/s:2682.40
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming `IMG_0423.png` is your first image. You have several options (ignoring renaming them) if your images do not start with "1", as in `IMG_0001.png` for your case.

## Use `-start_number`

You can use the `-start_number` input option to declare which file should begin the sequence:

```
ffmpeg -start_number 423 -i IMG_%04d.png … output
```

## Glob pattern

Another option is to use a glob pattern:

```
ffmpeg -pattern_type glob -i "IMG_*.png" … output
```

## Using a `cat`

You can pipe images to `ffmpeg` via `cat`.

```
cat *.png | ffmpeg -f image2pipe -c:v png -i - … output
```

---

Note that you may have to use a more recent `ffmpeg` for all of these examples to work. See the [FFmpeg Download](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page for links to builds for Linux, OS X, and Windows.

Comment: I tried a recent static build, but the output only shows the first frame. Still, I'm getting closer with your approach, thanks.

Comment: @AlexReynolds Can you update your question with the complete ffmpeg console output that results from your ffmpeg command? It's hard to say what might be going on without the output.

Comment: I edited my question to include the command I am running, along with output.

Comment: @AlexReynolds Is there a break in your numbering? Have you tried the other methods I listed? Can you provide a sample of the output?

Comment: No break. Same result using the glob. Did not try `cat`. I'll try to upload the movie file to Dropbox a little later when I have my laptop again.

Comment: Here's a link to the movie output: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/31495717/jigsaw.mp4 (this is the same as `foo.mp4`)

Comment: `jigsaw.mp4` seems to only contain 4 frames. If all 86 (I'm assuming this is how many there are) input frames were encoded, using the default frame rate of 25, the video would be 3.44 seconds in duration, not 16 milliseconds as it is now.

Comment: Yep, that's the problem with this command, as far as making output from only a few frames.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows this was the only thing I could get to work with a bunch of non-sequentially named jpegs (e.g. DMC003.JPG, DMC006.JPG, DMC009.JPG)

1. Rename to sequential files in Powershell:

```
dir *.jpg | %{$x=0} {Rename-Item $_ -NewName "Frame$($x.tostring('000000')).jpg"; $x++ }
```

Then in Anaconda prompt:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 15 -i Frame%06d.jpg output.mp4
```

This was using ffmpeg installed with conda:

```
conda create -n ffmpeg -c conda-forge ffmpeg
conda activate ffmpeg
```